# adding a new Ionic page

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am starting to use ionic for the first time and I have used the ionic generate page command to create a new page in my test app.  When doing so, the new page has been added to my template menu, however when I want to modify the new page in its corresponding html, the changes are not shown when compiling.  What do I need to configure so that the page is linked correctly?  I have been looking for information but where I have looked is outdated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you starting the server with `ionic serve` or how? It should load the changes this way

Comment: yes, I am starting ionic serve and it works fine, but I think there are some routing configuration I'm missing , the changes made in the home page are shown correctly but in the child page does not work  correctly. besides generating the page with ionic generate there is something else that it needs to be done.